# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = T\left(\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil\right) + T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right) + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence relation:

$$T(n) = T\left(\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} \right\rceil\right) + T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor\right) + 1$$

and I should solve it with $n = 2^m$

$$\begin{align}
T(2^m)
&= T\left(\left\lceil \frac{2^m}{2} \right\rceil\right) 
+ T\left(\left\lfloor \frac{2^m}{2} \right\rfloor\right) + 1 \\[6pt]
&= T\left(\left\lceil 2^{m-1} \right\rceil\right) + T\left(\left\lfloor 2^{m-1} \right\rfloor\right) + 1 \\[4pt]
&=2\cdot T(2^{m-1}) + 1
\end{align}$$

but now I am stuck. How can I get rid of $T(2^{m-1})$?

Comment: Repeat the process until you get to T(0) and T(1).

Comment: u mean i should solve $T(2^{m-1})$, but if do that i will get $T(2^{m-2})$ and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$T(2^m)+1=a_m$$
Then
$$a_m = 2a_{m-1}$$
Hence, it forms a geometric progression. So the general term is $$a_m=2^ma_0$$
$$\implies T(2^m)=2^mT(1)+2^m-1$$
 Hope you can proceed now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have got $$T(2^m)=2.T(2^{m-1})+1$$
Let $T(2^m)=2^m.a_m$ put in above we get
$$2^m.a_m=2^m.a_{m-1}+1$$
$$\therefore a_m-a_{m-1}=2^{-m}$$
$$. $$
Put values of m = m, m-1 , m-2 ,...,1 and add all we get
$$a_m-a_0=\sum_{m=1}^{m} 2^{-m}$$
Where a_0=T(1)=k (say)
$$ a_m=k+(1-2^{-m})$$
$$2^mT(2^m)=k+1-2^{-m}$$
$$T(2^m)=(T(1)+1).2^{-m}-1$$